# Lint SASS in Gulp before compiling

Tags: sass, gulp, lint

I'm new at Gulp and I'm trying to lint scss files before compiling them in order to avoid gulp watcher breaking.

My `gulpfile.js` looks like this now:

```
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);

// Sass compilation to css
gulp.task('build-css', function() {
  return gulp.src('source/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // Process the original sources
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write()) // Add the map to modified source.
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/css'));
});

// Configure which files to watch and what tasks to use on file changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('source/scss/**/*.scss', ['build-css']);
});
```

And when I enter a mistake in a scss file like:

```
body {
    color: $non-existing-var;
}
```

The gulp watcher shows error info but stops *watching* cause gulp breaks its execution. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume you are using [gulp-sass pluging](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass), if you are not using, I suggest you to do it. It is a wrapper over [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass), which is the C version: super fast :)

On [gulp-sass](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass) documentation, they already have you covered with [one example](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass#basic-usage), so your task should look like this:

```
gulp.task('build-css', function() {
  return gulp.src('source/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // Process the original sources
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write()) // Add the map to modified source.
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/css'));
});
```

Hope this helps you to accomplish what you are looking for :)